# How can I set a worksheet object based on a worksheet's codename?

Tags: vba, excel

The worksheet name may change. Because of that I want to set the worksheet object based on the worksheet's codename. How can I do this?

My best attempt so far is:

```
Sub UpdateNameDropdown()

    Dim wksName As String
    wksName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet16).Name

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Sheets(wksName)

End Sub
```

But I get a type mismatch error on the row `wksName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Sheet16.Name`

Comment: add double quotes to the sheet name: wksName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet16").Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the codename as a *String*

```
Sub CodeIt()
    Dim CodeName As String
    CodeName = "Sheet1"
    Dim WS As Worksheet, GetWorksheetFromCodeName As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If StrComp(WS.CodeName, CodeName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set GetWorksheetFromCodeName = WS
            Exit For
        End If
    Next WS
    MsgBox GetWorksheetFromCodeName.Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

This?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = Sheet16

    With wks
        Debug.Print .Name
        '~~> Do what you want
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gary's Student. I midified your function to the following:

```
Function GetWorksheetFromCodename(codeName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If StrComp(wks.codeName, codeName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set GetWorksheetFromCodename = wks
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wks
End Function
```

Comment: Why would you take such a long route?